# How do i architect automatic update of my clients

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a distributed application written in C# (4.0). It has become a substantial task to update all clients each time i create a new release. I do not want to go the ClickOnce way, since organisations that has bought my software in some cases do not wish to upgrade their clients.

How do i build such an update mechanism, for my clients? My thoughts are to implement a kind of launcher application that checks a server for newest version, updates that if required, and starts the new one. If no updates are available it simple starts the client application. Then i see a problem of updating the launcher application, should the client then be the one responsible for this?

How do I solve this in a proper and robust way, that ensures that the customer can configurate their clients for updates or not, and then allow the clients to function completely autonomically? That is, without user supervision.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a clearly separated multi tier application. Add all your business logic in a classLibrary. Add this Library as reference to your application. Afterwards create a checkFunction in your UI. (e.g. check a version "number" by calling a webService)

In case remote version > localVersion download new DLL (register in GAC if necessary) and demand restart of your application.

If your UI logic has changed too, download a complete new setup file (with removeOlder version = true) and demand user to start it or call process.Start on closed..

just a few ideas on your topic - hope this might help

Answer (score 0):

You could use ClickOnce and simply disable the CheckForUpdate : [MSDN : Disable Clickonce Default Updater](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/61b1efa6-3e54-43f8-afd4-e768a4939b61).

Comment: @H4mm3rHead : Of course, you could let the choice to your user the first time your app is launched to decide if this app is going to be updated or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of old, but you can take ideas and code pieces from the [Updater Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978574.aspx) which has the functionality you described.